# Python logging как остановить отключить?

Tags: python, логирование

Использую эту библиотеку для ведения лога работы программы logging. Но мне нужно в конце работы переименовать / очистить файл. А он не дает. видимо занят файл этим модулем. как прекратить отключить? я использовал так - не помогло

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename=logfile, filemode="a+", format="%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s")
logging.info("==== start == %d", my_pid)
...
logging.disabled = True
```

и в конце пытаюсь удалить файл - ошибка WindowsError: [Error 32]

Comment: можно руками добавлять/удалять FileHanlder. Какой контекст у задачи? Что вы хотите достичь переименовыванием/очисткой файла? (может изначально, следовало NullHandler настроить, чтобы ничего не писать или RotatingFileHandler, чтобы автоматически файлы переименовывать при достижении определённого размера)

Comment: `logging.shutdown()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Тогда модуль logging не будет выводить никаких сообщений.